# How do i make a paragraph wider?

Tags: html, css

I want to make my paragraph wider and also for it to remain in the centre of the page.

Whenever i change the width of my paragraph it ends up going to the left side of the page like this:
[image]

This is a snippet of my HTML and CSS file:

```css
.topheader {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-top: 80px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 50px;
```

```html
<p class="topheader">The best Macbook at your disposal!</p>
```

I want my paragraph to stay in the centre like this but for the paragraph to be wider.
[image]

Comment: simply remove width?

Comment: But i still want the  left and right side of the text to be wider.

Comment: margin: 0 auto;
or in your case
`margin: 80px auto 20px auto;`

Comment: removing width from your code will give the result shown on your screenshot

Comment: yes but i want my text to be wider than it shows in the second picture, like how  'font-size' makes the text bigger but i just want it to be more wide. Sorry I think i did not explain it properly.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your `p.topheader` except the silly `width: 50px` which is completely unnecessary. A paragraph occupies the width of containing block by default, you just need to center its text:

```
p.topheader {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You most likely have various rules on the containing block and its containing blocks in turn, messing up your layout. To reiterate: there is nothing wrong with your paragraph element in and out of itself, although I must mention it does not semantically fit in the context it is in -- as a heading, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

make width `100%` from  `50px`. It will cover paragraph default width.

```css
.topheader {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.9em;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100%;
```

```html
<p class="topheader">The best Macbook at your disposal!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.topheader {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-top: 80px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
```

```html
<p class="topheader">The best Macbook at your disposal!</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using flex.

Put a wrapper around the image and the paragraph like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <p>my paragraph</p>
 <img />
</div>
```

in the CSS use:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```